# Twilio - recordStatusCallBack not returning any json data when provided and aws api gateway link and working when node.js server locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, twilio

I wanted to access my call recording using the twilio's method using `recordingStatusCallBack` method, and i provide a link to the `recordingStatusCallBack` of my aws api gateway and set a POST request on my api gateway to return the json in my aws lambda while it was not working , but when i setup a node.js server on my machine and tunneled it using ngrok and provide that link on my `recordingStatusCallBack` attribute it works fine. why it didn't work on my aws api gateway ?

Comment: please share the code that you have tried (error msg,..). So that it's easier to understand.

Comment: @Nandha its not about the code its just that recordingStatusCallBack returns a json and on my api gateway i transfer that data to lambda and lambda just returns the complete "event" object which consist of json that was sent by twilio's method recordingStatusCallBack . I wanted to if any one has implemented it ?

Comment: Not entirely sure what's happening here, but Twilio never sends `application/json` requests. All Twilio requests are made as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Perhaps you need to tweak the API gateway to receive form encoded POST requests?

Comment: @philnash , i want to accept the recording url when call is completed, and i provide my api link on "recordingStatusCallBack" so that it could return me the data on my api gateway and that would pass it to my lambda and i am able to save it on the database

Comment: Right, I understand that, I'm saying that Twilio doesn't send JSON. Can you share the error you are getting?

Comment: well i am getting nothing when i console the body in my cloudwatch

Comment: Can you share how you set up the AWS API Gateway to receive these callbacks?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with api-gateway and twilio.

In your  **Body Mapping Templates** in api-gateway you need to add "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" as  **Content-Type** and paste this code to your template  :

```
## convert HTML POST data or HTTP GET query string to JSON

## get the raw post data from the AWS built-in variable and give it a nicer name
#if ($context.httpMethod == "POST")
 #set($rawAPIData = $input.path('$'))
#elseif ($context.httpMethod == "GET")
 #set($rawAPIData = $input.params().querystring)
 #set($rawAPIData = $rawAPIData.toString())
 #set($rawAPIDataLength = $rawAPIData.length() - 1)
 #set($rawAPIData = $rawAPIData.substring(1, $rawAPIDataLength))
 #set($rawAPIData = $rawAPIData.replace(", ", "&"))
#else
 #set($rawAPIData = "")
#end

## first we get the number of "&" in the string, this tells us if there is more than one key value pair
#set($countAmpersands = $rawAPIData.length() - $rawAPIData.replace("&", "").length())

## if there are no "&" at all then we have only one key value pair.
## we append an ampersand to the string so that we can tokenise it the same way as multiple kv pairs.
## the "empty" kv pair to the right of the ampersand will be ignored anyway.
#if ($countAmpersands == 0)
 #set($rawPostData = $rawAPIData + "&")
#end

## now we tokenise using the ampersand(s)
#set($tokenisedAmpersand = $rawAPIData.split("&"))

## we set up a variable to hold the valid key value pairs
#set($tokenisedEquals = [])

## now we set up a loop to find the valid key value pairs, which must contain only one "="
#foreach( $kvPair in $tokenisedAmpersand )
 #set($countEquals = $kvPair.length() - $kvPair.replace("=", "").length())
 #if ($countEquals == 1)
  #set($kvTokenised = $kvPair.split("="))
  #if ($kvTokenised[0].length() > 0)
   ## we found a valid key value pair. add it to the list.
   #set($devNull = $tokenisedEquals.add($kvPair))
  #end
 #end
#end

## next we set up our loop inside the output structure "{" and "}"
{
#foreach( $kvPair in $tokenisedEquals )
  ## finally we output the JSON for this pair and append a comma if this isn't the last pair
  #set($kvTokenised = $kvPair.split("="))
 "$util.urlDecode($kvTokenised[0])" : #if($kvTokenised.size() > 1 && $kvTokenised[1].length() > 0)"$util.urlDecode($kvTokenised[1])"#{else}""#end#if( $foreach.hasNext ),#end
#end
}
```